# I am implementing the ExternalData agent in VOLTTRON to get data from CAISO OASIS

Tags: csv, zip, volttron

I am implementing the ExternalData agent in the VOLTTRON platform to extract CSV data from the CAISO OASIS database.  OASIS returns .zip files containing the data in either XML or CSV.  I was able to crudely get the CSV data I wanted by modifying the _handle_csv function to extract the archive and open the resulting .csv into a file object prior to processing the csv data:

```
def _handle_csv(self, headers, request, url, source_topic, source_params):
    key_column = source_params.get("key", "")
    flatten = source_params.get("flatten", False)
    parse_columns = source_params.get("parse", [])

    # I am expecting a zip archive containing a csv file
    # so this is a workaround to read the zipfile and extract the csv
    # by creating a file object with open() after extracting
    # TODO find another way to get data w/o opening file so we dont
    # have to do housekeeping
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO(request.content))
    fname = z.namelist()
    z.extractall()
    file_obj = open(fname[0], 'r')

    # orig. file object assignment assuming request already in csv format
    # file_obj = StringIO(request.content)
```

I would like to find a better method to do this and avoid having to do excess housekeeping like closing the .csv and deleting it so files don't stack up in the agent-data directory.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ZipFile.open method. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open)

You can then pass the resulting file like object to the CSV parser.

```
file_obj = z.open(fname[0]) #Remove the extractall() call and this should do the trick.
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I must have skipped over that in the python docs.  I will try that.

Comment: You are welcome. This is probably good functionality to add to the agent. Would you mind creating an issue asking for this feature here: https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/issues